# Is this a known format for persisting an object?

Tags: format, object-persistence

I am analysing a system that persists HTML form input data like this:

```
a:2:{s:4:"form";a:1:{s:10:"labelWidth";i:150;}s:6:"fields";a:4:{s:15:"disp ...
```

Does anybody know if this is a known, documented format? Looks a bit like JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the output of [PHP's serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function. JSON's output looks quite different.

In PHP, you can decode the data by using [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

In what language do you need to process that bit of data? Maybe I know of an implementation for it.

Comment: Thanks! Very hard to Google this sort of thing.